# Python task in azure

Tags: python, azure-devops

I'm trying to run this python task in azure pipeline.

```html
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
     script: |
       import json
       import os
       import requests
       from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  
       url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId={id}&api-version=6.0"
```

But it gives me `##[error]Parameter 'toolPath' cannot be null or empty`

Comment: Have you tried providing a `toolPath`, perhaps pointing to a python interpreter?

Comment: since , python interpreter is optional argument haven't tried passing it. how do we provide the toolpath?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for toolPath as said by @msanford is for python Interpretor.

```
# Run a Python file or inline script
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    #scriptSource: 'filePath' # Options: filePath, inline
    #scriptPath: # Required when scriptSource == filePath
    #script: # Required when scriptSource == inline
    #arguments: # Optional
    #pythonInterpreter: # Optional
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
```

You can follow above syntax and provide `pythonInterpreter: /usr/bin/python3`, however path might be different.

To get exact path run your task in `Bask@3` and execute any random python3 command in script for example `python3 -m import sys` it will show you error with complete interpreter path and use that one.